# Altering or updating of nested data in DataFrame Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a very weird requirement in spark wherein I have to transform the data present in a dataframe.
So I read data from s3 bucket and transform them into a dataframe. This is being done fine, the next step is where the challenge lies.
Once the data is being read the data which is Json data needs to be transformed so that all data are consistent.

Sample data which I have

```
{"name": "John", "age": 24, "object_data": {"tax_details":""}}
{"name": "nash", "age": 26, "object_data": {"tax_details": {"Tax": "None"} } }
```

The issue is that tax_details field is string in first document and second document is having an object. I want to ascertain that everytime I put it as object, if that can be done by dataframe operation then it will be great. Else any pointer to do it will be great.
Looking for any help

Comment: you can read data and apply map transformation on row object check datatype on that particular column using x.get(i).isInstanceOf[String] then decide based on instance type what to do.

Comment: What do you want in the output type for `tax_details`?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale I want to keep it object type and at the same time will like to transform any data in where it's not object type to object type by simply passing {}